# How to add path of external application.properties file in deployment plan in weblogic 12c?

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I need to externalize the configuration of a spring boot application deployed on Weblogic 12.1.3 server.
Currently the application doesn't have a deployment plan specified.
I have removed the application.properties filefrom the application and built the war file. I have placed the application.properties file in a directory on the linux server where the application is being deployed.

I generated a deployment plan using weblogic.PlanGenerator tool and I added  element to provide path of the external peoperties file.

But while deploying the application on weblogic admin console with deployment plan, I am getting a validation error saying

`Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND <4:5> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'variable-definition@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan' instead of 'app-deployment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan' here in element deployment-plan@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/deployment-plan`

But I can see the element variable-definition in the weblogic generated deployment plan.
Can someone tell me what changes should I make to the deployment plan to externalize the application.properties from application?